# Problems running local copy of etherpad

Tags: java, etherpad

I get the following message when trying to execute etherpad/bin/run-local.sh:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/appjet/oui/main`

I created CLASSPATH variable,

`export CLASSPATH="/home/user/src/etherpad/trunk/infrastructure/build"`

but that didn't help either. Although I can clearly see net/appjet/oui package in the `build` directory.

Comment: (good to check! that wasn't the problem though; see below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this has been figured out:

http://groups.google.com/group/etherpad-open-source-discuss/browse_thread/thread/2d877d1b585e159c